# Finding Lines from noisy data

Tags: algorithm, line, cluster-analysis, mse

I have the following data https://ibb.co/G0VgFG6. In this case I would like to find three linear functions.

Methods that I tried:
1. Hough transform (radius, angle line paraemtrization), but the problem is the following https://ibb.co/jb3NPFh
2. Because for such problems it would be nice to have lines defined in least square sens I wanted to do also clustering and then MSE estimation, but it clusters vertically rather horizontally.

In general it would be nice to find in very flexible way linear functions defined in least square sense.

Comment: The question feels broad. Apparently, `algorithm` tag can be removed. YMMV. Regarding the question, based on domain knowledge you should identify the horizontal clusters here. After clustering you can get the line that fits well.

Comment: The horizontal point clusters only look that way, because of the different x and y scaling. If you are sure that the resulting clusters are somehow horizontal, you could use DBSCAN and adapt the distance you are using to something like d(a, b) = sqrt(lambda*(a.x-b.x)^2 + (a.y-b.y)^2)   where larger lambda in [0, 1]. Afterwards perform linear regression on each cluster.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it, but in real scenario data can be rotated, because actually it's LiDAR data. And in theory I know that some space there is, but I don't know how big.

Comment: @AndrzejReinke maybe tell us a bit more about your exact scenario. Currently it is hard to grasp what you want to achieve.

Comment: @SaiBot so the scenario is the following: the robot is in orchard (there are trees for example) and the robot needs to travel based on lidar data. The trees have a checker structure so i wanted to cluster each row and then do ransac to calculate the function to approximate coefficient a and b (in a linear function) and then calculate the number of rows that are passed

Comment: I am lost, what does the checker structure have to do with the rows of the lidar scan. Shouldn't the lidar data be 3d?

Comment: no, if it's 2D lidar :)